# perform an action without page redirection on comment.create event

Tags: php, ajax

Im using facebook comments i want to send page url to my data base or txt file on the event without redicting the page. I need help..I  tried alot..plz

Page URL code-

```
<?php
 $protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') 

                      === FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';


    $host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

      $script   = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

      $params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

      $currentUrl = $protocol . '://' . $host . $script . '?' . $params;


?>
```

My event Create code.

```
<script>
            $("document").ready(function(){
                //catch like event
                FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(href) {
< Code for sending page url to database or txt sholud be here >
                });
                //catch unlike event
                FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove', function(href) {
                    alert('You just unliked '+href);
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use xmlhttprequest,
see through these following links

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/